# Change colour of Back Button, Navigation Title in UIPopoverController

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationbar, uipopovercontroller

I have added the `UIActivityViewController` in the contentView of `UIPopoverController`. And trying to open `Print` Option which is navigating in `UIPopoverController` itself. I am getting that view

[image]    [image]

And I am getting the color of Title (Print Options / Printer) and back button is white , I want it to blue.this is only in case of `UIPopoverController`. Otherwise al is fine.

Please suggest !!!

Answer (score 0):

For the **Title** use:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blueColor]}];
```

For the **arrow and text** of back button:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

And of course if you have an object of UIPopoverController you have to apply the styles from navigation bar:

```
popoverController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes;
```

Comment: Not working for back button and for it's arrow colour

Comment: Can you show some code and also give a try this: `self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];` and/or `[UINavigationBar appearance].tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];`

Answer (score 0):

In your viewDidLoad method for that controller:

```
 for (UIView *subview in self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews) [subview setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```